# Finding eigenvectors of an observable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

I am trying to find the eigenvectors of the operator:
$$
S_{u}=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left( 
        \begin{matrix}
        \cos{\theta} & e^{-i\phi}\sin{\theta}  \\
        e^{i\phi}\sin{\theta} & -\cos{\theta} 
        \end{matrix}
         \right)
$$

I have already found that the eigenvalues are $+\frac{\hbar}{2}$ and $-\frac{\hbar}{2}$, and that the eigenvectors are something like:

$$|+\rangle_u=\left( 
        \begin{array}{c}
        1 \\
        \frac{1-\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}}e^{i\phi}
        \end{array}
         \right)
\quad\text{and}\quad
|-\rangle_u=\left( 
        \begin{array}{c}
        1 \\
        -\frac{1+\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}}e^{i\phi}
        \end{array}
         \right)
$$

But how do I write these in a more elegant way (in terms of half angles $\phi/2$ and $\theta/2$)?

Comment: If in doubt then a way forward might be to use WolframAlpha in two steps. First http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7Bcos(theta),sin(theta)*e%5E(-i*phi)%7D,%7B+sin(theta)*e%5E(i*phi),+-cos(theta)%7D%7D  follwed by http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cot(theta)-csc(theta)  You can also access the step by step solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is a little bit excessive: you want to rephrase things in terms of the half-angle $\theta/2$, but $\phi$ should be left as-is. With that in mind, then, you simply see $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ as double-angle trigonometrics applied to $\theta/2$, and use the standard trigonometric identities with this in mind:
$$
\sin(\theta) = 2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2),
$$
and
$$
\sin^2(x)=\frac12-\frac12\cos(2x)
$$
with $x=\theta/2$, rephrased as
$$
1-\cos(\theta)=2\sin^2(\theta/2)
$$
(and similarly $1+\cos(\theta) = 2\cos^2(\theta/2)$). You then put these into your formulas to get
$$
\frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} 
= \frac{2\cos^2(\theta/2)}{2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)}
= \frac{\cos(\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)}
$$
and similarly
$$
\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} 
= \frac{2\sin^2(\theta/2)}{2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)}
= \frac{\sin(\theta/2)}{\cos(\theta/2)}.
$$

The only thing left to do now is to multiply by the denominators, and that leaves your states in the canonical form,
$$|+\rangle_u=\left( 
        \begin{array}{c}
        {\cos(\theta/2)} \\
        {\sin(\theta/2)}e^{i\phi}
        \end{array}
         \right)
\quad\text{and}\quad
|-\rangle_u=\left( 
        \begin{array}{c}
        {\sin(\theta/2)} \\
        -{\cos(\theta/2)}e^{i\phi}
        \end{array}
         \right),
$$
though it can help to rephrase the second state as
$$
|-\rangle_u=\left( 
        \begin{array}{c}
        {\sin(\theta/2)} \\
        -{\cos(\theta/2)}e^{i\phi}
        \end{array}
         \right)
=\left( 
        \begin{array}{c}
        {\cos\left(\frac{\pi-\theta}{2}\right)} \\
        \sin\left(\frac{\pi-\theta}{2}\right)e^{i(\phi+\pi)}
        \end{array}
         \right),
$$
where the transformation $\theta\mapsto\pi-\theta$, $\phi\mapsto\phi+\pi$ makes it explicit that $|-\rangle_u$ has the same form as $|+\rangle_u$ under an inversion in the Bloch sphere.

Answer (score 4):

Normalizing the kets and using trigonometric identities : $\cos\theta=\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$ and $\sin\theta=2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$. You can write the eigenkets as :

$$|+\rangle_{u}=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}}\cos\frac{\theta}{2} \\e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$|-\rangle_{u}=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}}\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \\-e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix}.$$